# Java NamingEnumeration - Getting a single element out of a NamingEnumeration

Tags: java, active-directory

I am trying to fetch some users from Active Directory group and update them in another one of our site.
The task is almost done except for the part where I need to fetch the user ID from NamingEnumeration and pass it onto another method which will update it through a REST API call. Below is a part of the code where I am fetching users from AD group:

```
DirContext myContext = new InitialDirContext(envVars);

    SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String[] attributes = { "cn", "member"};
    searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);

    String filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=GROUP_NAME))";
    NamingEnumeration values = myContext.search("DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX",filter,searchCtrls);

    while (values.hasMoreElements())
    {
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) values.next();
        Attributes attribs = result.getAttributes();
        if (null != attribs)
        {
            for (NamingEnumeration ae = attribs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                String attributeID = atr.getID();
                for (
                    Enumeration vals = atr.getAll(); 
                    vals.hasMoreElements(); 
                    System.out.println(attributeID+": "+vals.nextElement())                     
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this, the output is something like below:

> member: CN=USERNAME,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX
>   member: CN=USERNAME,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX

Basically, I need to fetch this CN i.e. USERNAME alone, which I will pass onto another method.

I did try to get them in a String array and process them, to no avail and I am running short of time.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just `break` as soon as you have one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did get around this problem.
Below approach worked for me.

```
if (null != attribs)
        {
            for (NamingEnumeration ae = attribs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements();)
            {

                Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                for (
                    Enumeration vals = atr.getAll(); 
                    vals.hasMoreElements(); 
                ) {
                        list.add(vals.nextElement().toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

I let the output inside a list and clipped the unwanted parts to obtain the CN alone.
Would be glad if this helps someone in the future.